# Trying to install VMware-Player-12.1.1-3770994.x86_64.bundle but is planting for strange reason!

Tags: 16.04, vmware-player

I tried a few times installing VMware-Player-12.1.1-3770994.x86_64.bundle free package (16.04), but every time the following message:

There was a problem opening the file “/home/master/Downloads/V…1.1-3770994.x86_64.bundle”.
The file you opened has some invalid characters. If you continue editing this file you could corrupt this document.
You can also choose another character encoding and try again.

I tried to reinstall, to continue, but no issue, planting the installation with "dark window".

What to do?
Thanks
Serros

Comment: How are you opening/running the file? Did you make it executable?

Comment: Well, I did download this file and executed with the command "Open with gedit", but frankly I don't know if it's correct?

Comment: there is your issue, I posted an answer.

Comment: You don't open these files with gedit. you run them from terminal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what you need to do to install this:

`cd /home/master/Downloads`

`sudo chmod a+x VMware-Player-12.1.1-3770994.x86_64.bundle` (you can use <kbd>Tab</kbd> to autocomplete this filename once you have typed enough characters that there are no other filenames that it could be)

`sudo ./VMware-Player-12.1.1-3770994.x86_64.bundle`

This should work for you! Let me know if you have any questions, or get an error message.

Comment: excellent, working immediately well.
thanks
serros